# How to take element from list and make new list

Tags: python, python-3.x

My task is to make from string a list. Then move all elements from list to another list and convert it to string again.
This is what I've done:

```
    def string_list(sentence: str) -> str:
        result = []
        sentence = sentence.split(" ")
        while sentence:
            for i in range(len(sentence)):
                tmp_var = sentence[i]
                result.append(tmp_var)
                sentence.remove(tmp_var)
        return " ".join(result)

print(string_list("Hey, how's it going?"))
```

But I got this error message: **IndexError: list index out of range**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `while sentence`?

Comment: Furthermore *never* remove elements of a list you are currently iterating over.

Comment: Why not just `setence = setence.split(' '); return ''.join(sentence)`? Or `return ''.join(setence.split(' '))`.

Comment: Some basics you should learn before doing... deletion in a while loop. First, use a FOR loop, or even better, a function that already exists.

Comment: @ChristianDean Because in next step I want to sort elements and create a new string

Comment: @AlTs Well you never mentioned that in the question - or code for that matter.

Comment: @AlTs Anyway, your code would still be: `''.join(sorted(setence.split(' ')))`

Comment: @ChristianDean Yeah, I just wanted to learn first how to correctly move elements from one list to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you can try list comprehension :

```
string_1="Hey, how's it going?"



origional_list=[i for i in string_1]
string_to_list=[i for i in origional_list if i!=',' and i!="'" and i!=' ']

print("String to list : {}".format(string_to_list))
list_to_string=("".join(origional_list))


print("list to String : {}".format(list_to_string))
```

output:

```
String to list : ['H', 'e', 'y', 'h', 'o', 'w', 's', 'i', 't', 'g', 'o', 'i', 'n', 'g', '?']
list to String : Hey, how's it going?
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def string_list(str):
    result = []
    sentence = str.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(sentence)):
        result.append(sentence[i])
    return " ".join(result)

print(string_list("Hey, how's it going?"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def string_list(sentence):
    result = []
    sentence = sentence.split(" ")
    for word in sentence:
        result.append(word)

    sentence = []
    return " ".join(result)

print(string_list("Hey, how's it going?"))
```

I don't quiet understand why you are moving the words from one list to the other, but in python you can make use of the looping mechanism instead of using indices which may cause a hassle.

Hope my provided answer fixes your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use `list.pop` to empty the input data

```
def string_list(sentence: str) -> str:
    result = []
    sentence = sentence.split(" ")
    if sentence:
        word = sentence.pop()
        result.append(word)
        while word:
            if not sentence:
                break
            word = sentence.pop()
            result.append(word)

    return ' '.join(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because at each iteration you remove one item of sentence so its length decreases. But your for loop still iterates through the initial sentence length.

Comment: So I can't use remove function in for loop?

Comment: Not recommended if you use indexes.